# How do I use python to find a number of unique groups such that each subset within the group has at most X elements from a given array of Y?

Tags: python, recursion

[This is the problem but I do not fully understand what I need to do, especially the functions of n and m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piM1n.jpg)

I have tried looking for the patterns to use but I am stuck

So far I have written

```
def howManyGroups (n,m):
    if n >= 2:
       Return 2
    else:
```

This is my first time posting a question so I am sorry if something is wrong

Comment: Could you please construct a small example, and what the output would be for that example and why? Maybe with n = 5 and m = 2. Frankly I do not understand the problem. "Given an array of n non-unique elements". It sounds like you need to know the array, not just the number n. For instance, if n = 6, then the answer would be different if the array is [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3] than if it is [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], or if it is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], even though all those arrays have 6 elements each.

Comment: Where did you get this problem? It is worded in a very ambiguous way and is hard to understand. Presumably it is not a hard problem, but it is so badly worded that I can't make sense of it.

Comment: Hello so one of the example is n = 7, m = 3, output = 8, I wish there was a way to show more of the example in the matrix form but I narrowed the pattern to m = max # of same colors, n = # of columns, output = # of rows. And this is a problem from my professor and I do agree I’m having a really hard time understanding the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```py
def how_many_groups(n, m):
    m = min(m, n)
    if n == 0 or m <= 1:
        return 1
    return how_many_groups(n, m - 1) + how_many_groups(n - m, m)
```

The logic, as far as I understand the requirement:

- Base cases: (1) If there are no elements then there's only one way (`n == 0`). (2) If the maximum of elements in a group is 1 then there's also only one way (`m == 1`).
- Reduction: (1) Reduce the maximum `m` by 1 and count (`m - 1`). (2) Then make sure there's a least one group of size `m` and count the remaining possibilities on the reduced population (`n - m`). Add both counts.
- The `m = min(m, n)` is to make sure that `m` is at most `n`, because a bigger `m` doesn't matter regarding the count. You could replace it with `if m > n: return how_many_groups(n, n)`.

Comment: Or `m = min(m, n)`

Comment: Thank you for helping me with my problem! Some of the test did not work because “maximum recursion depth exceeded” error. I have tried import sys and setting the limit higher but it still did not work so I was wondering it if had something to do with the base case. One of the failed test is n = 8 and m<=8

Comment: @IanDang Do you get a `RecursionError` for `n = 8, m = 8` or a wrong result?

Comment: @Timus  for that I got a recursion error it said: name: 01 Recursion: n = 8, m <= 8
status: failed
output: Test Failed: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Comment: @IanDang Okay, then my guess would be that `m = 0` is allowed. I don't know what the result is supposed to be for that case but I've changed it to `1` (see edit). Nevertheless, you'll run into `RecursionError`s for something like `how_many_groups(666, 666)` etc.